# Minecraft 1.7.10 + forge

Tags: minecraft

How do I install minecraft 1.7.10 and forge on a raspberry pi 3. Since I have this friend who wants me to install **1** mod to play on his server.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just install it regularly, i.e. download forge from the site, run the jarfile with java -jar (forge-installation).jar

but keep in mind, to use 1.7 forge requires java 7 iirc.

edit: apparently only some builds of forge work, and you don't get sound. I found this information from https://html.dynu.net/index.php/how-to-setup-minecraft-on-raspberry-pi-forge-version-1-12-2/, but it should apply to 1.7 versions as well. Just experiment a bit (and maybe follow the url for the guide i listed, but with a different download).

another edit: apparently it doesn't work that way... try following the guide but using the download for 1.7 forge

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft is a game that allows users to build with blocks in a 3D environment. There are many different versions of Minecraft, but the most popular one is Minecraft 1.7.10 because it has many mods that allow for more customized gameplay. Forge is a modding platform that lets players install other mods onto Minecraft 1.7.10, and on Raspberry Pi 3s specifically, it's very easy to do!

To install Forge on your Raspberry Pi 3, you'll need an internet connection and your device's IP address handy. First, open up the terminal window and type in the following command: curl -sL https://install forge-1 7 10-installer .jar | java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar installer . jar (Note: if you're using an older version of Java than 8 Update 131, which is what comes preinstalled on Raspbian Jessie Lite 2016-05-27 , then use this command instead: curl -sL https://forge download fileforge 17 10 installer jar | java –version) This will download the Forge installer JAR file from GitHub; once it's downloaded, just press Enter to run it!

The next step is inputting your device's IP address into the text field at the top of the window and clicking "Install." After installation has completed successfully (it should only take a few minutes), click "Start Server" to begin playing on your own private server with all of your friends!

Answer (score -1):

You can find it in apt try

```
apt search minecraft
```

and you will find it. Then install it with the package name

Comment: What of the 12 shown programs is the right one?